# What does the * do when used as part of an attribute selector?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I'm looking at the following code:

```
var script = document.querySelector('script[src*="' + file + '"]');
```

What does the `*` component of the selector do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @Teemu: Ha, I *knew* someone would paste the wrong link first. Happens every time. No, it's not a universal selector. Read the question.

Comment: @Teemu: It's all good ;) I just find it funny how this keeps happening every time.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep, it's not an universal selector, the link is fixed now ; ). I'll bookmark the good dup for the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` at attribute selector matches `file` if `file` string is contained within the attribute